# Traversing and manipulating javascript object with arrays into single object matching a format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've been racking my brains with this one, I've attempted to resolve this with a number of recursive functions with no joy so I thought I'd ask to see if anyone has any solutions.

I have an object which is a mixture of JSON and arrays, in short, I need to strip out the arrays but retain their values where the array was originally found.

Here's console.log of the object/array:

Object {type: Array[1], properties: Object}

1. properties: Object
2. 1. associatedMedia: Array[1]
   2. 1. 0: Object
      2. 1. properties: Object
      3. 1. url: Array[1]
         2. 1. 0: "/programmes/p00t64wh.emp"
         3. length: 1
         4. **proto**: Array[0]
         5. **proto**: Object
      4. type: Array[1]
      5. 1. 0: "MediaObject"
         2. length: 1
         3. **proto**: Array[0]
      6. **proto**: Object
      7. length: 1
      8. **proto**: Array[0]
   3. byArtist: Array[1]
   4. 1. 0: Object
      2. 1. properties: Object
      3. 1. name: Array[1]
         2. 1. 0: "Foster the People"
         3. length: 1
         4. **proto**: Array[0]
         5. url: Array[1]
         6. 1. 0: "/music/artists/e0e1a584-dd0a-4bd1-88d1-c4c62895039d"
         7. length: 1
         8. **proto**: Array[0]
         9. **proto**: Object
      4. type: Array[1]
      5. 1. 0: "MusicGroup"
         2. length: 1
         3. **proto**: Array[0]
      6. **proto**: Object
      7. length: 1
      8. **proto**: Array[0]
   5. image: Array[1]
   6. 1. 0: "/radio1/chart/artwork/ussm11002931.jpg"
      2. length: 1
      3. **proto**: Array[0]
   7. name: Array[1]
   8. 1. 0: "Pumped Up Kicks"
      2. length: 1
      3. **proto**: Array[0]
   9. publication: Array[1]
   10. 1. 0: Object
       2. 1. properties: Object
       3. 1. partOfSeries: Array[1]
          2. 1. 0: Object
          3. 1. properties: Object
             2. 1. name: Array[1]
             3. 1. 0: "Lauren Laverne"
                2. length: 1
                3. **proto**: Array[0]
             4. url: Array[1]
             5. 1. 0: "/programmes/b00c000j"
                2. length: 1
                3. **proto**: Array[0]
             6. **proto**: Object
             7. type: Array[1]
             8. 1. 0: "Series"
             9. length: 1
             10. **proto**: Array[0]
             11. **proto**: Object
          4. length: 1
          5. **proto**: Array[0]
          6. publishedOn: Array[1]
          7. 1. 0: Object
          8. 1. properties: Object
             2. 1. name: Array[1]
             3. 1. 0: "From BBC Radio 6 Music"
                2. length: 1
                3. **proto**: Array[0]
             4. url: Array[1]
             5. 1. 0: "/6music/"
                2. length: 1
                3. **proto**: Array[0]
             6. **proto**: Object
             7. type: Array[1]
             8. 1. 0: "BroadcastService"
             9. length: 1
             10. **proto**: Array[0]
             11. **proto**: Object
          9. length: 1
          10. **proto**: Array[0]
          11. **proto**: Object
       4. type: Array[1]
       5. 1. 0: "Episode"
          2. length: 1
          3. **proto**: Array[0]
       6. **proto**: Object
       7. length: 1
       8. **proto**: Array[0]
   11. **proto**: Object
3. type: Array[1]
4. 1. 0: "MusicRecording"
   2. length: 1
   3. **proto**: Array[0]
5. **proto**: Object

The desired conversion should look like the following code but it's not a big problem if, for example, 'properties' remained but all arrays should be stripped out into an object.

```
{
    'associatedMedia': {
        'url':'/programmes/p00t64wh.emp',
        'type':'MediaObject'
    },
    'byArtist': {
        'name':'Foster the People',
        'url':'/music/artists/e0e1a584-dd0a-4bd1-88d1-c4c62895039d',
        'type':'MusicGroup'
    },
    'publication': {
        'publishedOn':{
            'name':'From BBC Radio 6 Music',
            'url':'/6music/',
            'type':'BroadcastService'
        },
        'partOfSeries':{
            'name':'Lauren Laverne',
            'url':'programmes/b00c000j',
            'type':'Series'
        }
        'type':'http://schema.org/Episode'
    }
    'image':'/radio1/chart/artwork/ussm11002931.jpg',
    'name':'Pumped up Kicks',
    'type':'MusicRecording'
}
```

All keys and values are dynamically assigned however the object that needs to be converted will follow: Object > key/value > 0 > properties > key/value

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Can you possibly make up an easier example? So that we can focus on the core problem. In this format the question hardly gets much attention. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies if not clear but I think the writing it down has actually helped and I've come up with a solution. Needs a bit of refactoring and cleaning up but I have the concept of how to handle this now.

Comment: @Daniel, please post your solution here so future users may benefit from your knowledge. You also earn reputation for your profile